# Problema al tratar de leer un struct en c++

Tags: c++, struct

tengo este codigo con el cual ingreso datos en en un archivo .dat

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
FILE* arch;
    struct stregistro
    {
        char codigo[100];
        char nombre[10];
        char direccion[10];
        int edad;
        float nota;

    }
    persona;
    arch=fopen("datos.dat","ab");
    cout<<"digite los datos: "<<endl;
    cout<<"ingrese el codigo"<<endl;
    cin>>persona.codigo;
    cout<<"nombre: "<<endl;
    cin>>persona.nombre;
    cout<<"direccion: "<<endl;
    cin>>persona.direccion;
    cout<<"edad: "<<endl;
    cin>>persona.edad;
    cout<<"nota: "<<endl;
    cin>>persona.nota;
    fseek(arch,sizeof(stregistro),SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&persona,sizeof(stregistro),1,arch);

    return 0;
}
```

y necesito ayuda con este codigo deberia ser para sacar los datos del codigo que se ingresa pero no me funciona porfavor ayuda

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    FILE* arch;
    struct stregistro
    {
        char codigo[10];
        char nombre[10];
        char direccion[10];
        int edad;
        float nota;

    }
    persona;
    int i;
    char wcodigo[10];
    arch=fopen("datos.dat","r");

    cout<<"ingrese el codigo: "<<endl;
    cin>>wcodigo;
    i=0;
    while (!feof(arch))
    {
        fseek(arch,i*sizeof(stregistro),SEEK_SET);
        fread(&persona,sizeof(stregistro),1,arch);
        if(persona.codigo==wcodigo)
        {
        cout<<"nombre: "<<persona.nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"direccion: "<<persona.direccion<<endl;
        cout<<"edad: "<<persona.edad<<endl;
        cout<<"nota: "<<persona.nota<<endl;
        cout<<endl; 
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ser un poco mas específico? ¿Que es lo que no te funciona? ¿Te da error? ¿No te compila?...

Answer (score 0):

He detectado tres errores por lo cual no funciona.

1) En el primer **main()** cuando declaras la estructura **stregistro**, el campo **codigo** lo definís como un array de 100 y en el segundo **main()** lo definís como un array de 10.

2) En el primer **main()** si queres usar un **fseek()** que no afecta al funcionamiento, porque el archivo lo abrís con **fopen()** cuyo modo es "ab", por lo tanto todo lo que escribas siempre se escribira al final.

3) En el segundo **main()** la comparación de arrays no es correcta, ya que es un string, para esto debes usar la función **strcmp()**.

O sea, en vez de escribir:

```
if(persona.codigo==wcodigo)
```

Deberías escribir:

```
if(0 == strcmp(persona.codigo, wcodigo))
```